# How can specifying the absolute path $ /usr/bin/python have a different result than $ python when its aliased to the same path?

Tags: python, bash, alias, absolute-path, jcc

I'm trying to `make` PyLucene which has a required dependency JCC.  (JCC is a code generator for calling Java from Python.)

Note: OS is Mac OS X 10.7.4.

The included make script runs:

```
$ /usr/bin/python -m jcc
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named jcc
```

but running the following is successful:

```
$ python -m jcc
```

Even though python points to /usr/bin/python:

```
$ whereis python
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

When the `python` alias points to `/usr/bin/python`, how can these results be different?

Comment: `whereis` searches through a list of certain directories (listed in man) for source/binary and manuals sections, i suggest you execute `which python` which searches only for binaries in $PATH, to find out excatly which python is being used

Answer (score 1):

Try running `python --version` on both and see if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be the hash table.  Bash keeps a table of remembered commands - it does not search `$PATH` each time.  If `python` was called before the `alias` was setup then the hash table will get used.  My understanding though is that aliases are expanded before the hash table is searched, but the man pages are not clear on that.

Check this by listing the hash table using the `hash` command.  Reset the hash table using `hash -d python`.

However, I note that you are using `make`, although your example is command-line.  Aliases are not inherited (by default) by child processes, and it would probably be a support nightmare if it did.  So `make` is not using your alias.